# Tableau: How to perform reverse geo-coding in Tableau 10

Tags: reverse-geocoding, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau world. I have traffic data in a .csv file containing latitude and longitude values. I have loaded the data into Tableau as a symbol Map. I need to show the corresponding location on the map in Tableau. Can somebody suggest me how to do this?

Another concern is that in tableau maps, there is no caption for any location as we can see in Google Maps. Can I change a raw map to more informative in terms of showing location data such as a city, an IT campus, etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "corresponding locations" means something like "123 Examplestreet, 1234 Example City", you won't be able to do it in Tableau. 
You will need an external process using for example the Google API that helps you with that.
The only thing that Tableau is capable of is displaying Lat/Lon coordinates or Geographic names on a map.

You can get more details with map layers "Map/Map Layers" to display for example street names. Alternatively you can use an external WMS service to display custom maps (eg. https://www.mapbox.com/blog/tableau-integration/ ).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'd used "Map Layers" option yesterday to make the map show location names to a certain extent. I'll think about reverse geo-coding as a separate process outside Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau doesn't have any native capability to do that. 
If you wanted to do it nonetheless, I'd use Tableau's R Integration and do the reverse geocoding from there.

This way you wouldn't have to take your data "outside" of Tableau.